# SpecFlow: Associated Automation not showing Tests in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, automated-tests, specflow

We are using SpecFlow, Selenium WebDriver[C#] with VSTS 2017. In Test Explorer Associate Tests option is disabled and hence not able to do automation association to test case. In Automation Association tab of Test case Choose Tests window is not displaying with any of my tests which are present in Test Explorer.

BDD Frame work : SpecFlow 2,
VSTS 2017 Tool,
Unit Test Provider: SpecRun,
Project Type: Test Project,
Visual Studio default Architecture: X64,
Note: We are using Azure DevOps, only for automation association we are using VSTS.

Comment: You might need to upgrade to SpecFlow 3 maybe?

Comment: It also might be that Azure DevOps doesn't support text discovery with SpecRun, too.

Comment: A tool I develop, SpecSync automates this process by automatically creating, updating and linking test cases to scenarios. https://www.specsolutions.eu/services/specsync/

Comment: Hi, Apologies for the delayed reply. Upgrading to SpecFlow 3 is having so many dependencies for us, so I have not tried to upgrade Specflow3 of our current solution. But, I have done a POC by creating new project with Specflow3, but.. still I do not find the option enable for automation Association for SpeRun Tests. I have recently installed updates for VSTS 2019, post that Associate Button is Enable and upon clicking on it, saying that, for SpecRun Tests Association is not supported and it supports only for NUnit, XUnit and MSTest frameworks only.

Comment: I think, SpecSync is to create or update the test cases in Azure DevOps with feature file steps. In our case, test cases are written by Manual Test Team separately and Automation Scripts BDD steps are different. We do not want to update the test cases with BDD feature file steps. We need only automation code association for automation build run process.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to add an association to a test case from the test explorer like this
[image]

Right click on the test you want to associate then click on the associate to test case.  I have checked and it works in VS 2017 and 2019.

Comment: After clicking on 'Associate to Test Case' option getting error message "Cannot associate tests discovered by executor://specrun/ executorv3.0.377. Association is only supported for the following test types - MSTEST, Xunit, Ordered and Generic tests."

Comment: Are you using NUnit with Specflow? It looks like it only supports tests of type MSTEST or Xunit.  You can pretty much modify the decorator to MSTests and add a few using and it should work the same.  I always use MSTest myself.  Never bothered with other framework.

Comment: We are using SpecRun as unit test provider with SpecFlow. We have the requirements like parallel thread execution and multi browser targeting. I have tried a POC to migrate existing tests to MSTEST framework, but multi thread model is not working. we are using 3 threads to run automation, if this is not going to workout in MSTest then test execution time is going to be triple which is not likely to be good for us. One more thing is, MSTEST generates reports in .trx file when we run tests from command prompt. where as SpecRun generates html report which is easily understandable and simple.

Comment: Understood.  If you want the integration with the Azure DevOps test cases you need to run a test from the list you mentionned. MSTEST, Xunit, Ordered and Generic tests.  You can always run the specflow test in your pipeline and upload the result using the publish test result task but you wont have the nice report from specrun.  Or you can use the specflow+ task: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=techtalk.techtalk-specflow-plus which generates nice reports in the build also.

Comment: you can also try the specflow report generator task: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=mmajcica.SpecFlowReportGenerator